# In Google Plus API,GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch returning nil although using right clientId,clientSecret,access token

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, google-plus, google-authentication

In iOS app, I am using below code to **retrieve user's authentication in another view controller of which user is already logged in using google plus sign in API**:

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
                                                 initWithScope:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
                                                 clientID:CLIENT_ID
                                                 clientSecret:CLIENT_SECRET
                                                 keychainItemName:NAME
                                                 delegate:self
                                                 finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:_googlePlusCtrl animated:YES];
```

**But when i am running below code then viewController.authentication.accessToken give nil value and viewController.authentication also gives nil value.**

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error 
{
    if (error != nil) {
        // Authentication failed
        NSLog(@"failed");
    } else {
        // Authentication succeeded
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
}
```

EDIT: in response to Ashim's comment ...

I have this in app delegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url 
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication 
                         annotation:annotation];
}
```

Do i have to write any specific code in this function?

Comment: do you implement the method - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url in your AppDelegate ?

Comment: I have this in app delegate :  - (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation {
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}  Do i have to write any specific code in this function?

Comment: It's a small point, but you should probably be using the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope.

Comment: @class : I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: @class : It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

the code i have (and the code in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224309/ios-google-authentication-code?rq=1)) use only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me for scope.  my code is close to the same as yours in most places (including your appDelegate implementation), but the scope differs for me in my google+ button IBAction as follows (*and for the purpose of this question, ignore the difference in use of interface idiom and type of viewController transition; it's not relevant to the answer, just shows how it's used in a different way for the close to the same effect*):

```
    NSString *scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"; // scope for Google+ API
    SEL gPlusSignInFinished = @selector(googlePlusSignInViewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *gtmOAuth2ViewController
      = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:scope
                                                 clientID:GPLUS_CLIENT_ID
                                             clientSecret:GPLUS_CLIENT_SECRET
                                         keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                 delegate:self
                                         finishedSelector:gPlusSignInFinished];

    // note that the controller is passed in both situations for differing idioms
    if (UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone == UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom)
        [self presentModalViewController:gtmOAuth2ViewController animated:YES];
    else
        [self gPlusPopover:gtmOAuth2ViewController];
```

Comment: I already tried with by using this scope :  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me. But it doesnt works.